# Setting and getting values using service angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

basically its setting and getting an array.

```
 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

 @Injectable()    
 export class Svc {

     constructor() {}

     private _updatedArray: Array < any > = [];
     setColDefs(columns: any) {
         this._updatedArray.push(columns);
         console.log(columns);
     }
     getColDef() {
         return this._updatedArray;
     }
}
```

In one of my componnet i set the array as below:

```
...
this._listSvc.setColDefs(colDefArray);
...
```

In my other componnet,

```
...
import { Svc } from '../services/mySvc.svc'; 

@Component({ 
...
}) 

export class EditComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy{ 

    constructor( 
        private _editCompSvc: Svc 
    ){} 

    ngOnInit() { 
        console.log(this._editCompSvc.getColDef()); 
    }
```

But no idea why the getColDef always giving an empty list. Even in my service the getter function returns an empty list. Any idea guys? Thanks inadvance.

My module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { routing } from './routes/myroute.route';
import { Svc } from './services/mySvc.svc'

import { ListComponent } from './actions/list.comp';
import { EditComponent } from './actions/edit.comp';

@NgModule({
    imports:
    [
        routing
    ],

    declarations:
    [
        ListComponent,
        EditComponent
    ],

    providers:
    [Svc]
})

export class Module { }
```

Comment: this._listSvc.setColDefs(colDefArray); this one is called before console.log(this._editCompSvc.getColDef());

Comment: yeah it shud be called first and set my columns so that my edit componenent can get the columns

Comment: yes man , so you found the issue?

Comment: yeah its like that already

Comment: but the array is undefined in my edit component

Comment: when i call my get method

Comment: @blackdaemon Does the `_updatedArray` `console log` gets called ?

Comment: yeah but the value is undefined

Comment: @blackdaemon are you sure that `this._listSvc.setColDefs(colDefArray);
` is get called with valid array ? Does the `colDefArray` has a full array when used in that call ?

Comment: yeah in my set i get the array with values. But in my getter its undefined

Comment: @blackdaemon It can't be undefined because you initialize it for each service instance as an empty array. Are you getting empty array ?

Comment: yeah empty array sorry

Comment: @blackdaemon can you provide the code where you call the setColdefs?

Comment: @blackdaemon and you do not have providers array in each component also? Only in NgModule?

Comment: yeah only provide in my module not in each components

Comment: @brijmcq: I have already provided the codes

Comment: @blackdaemon what I meant is the code on your other component where you use this._listSvc.setColDefs(colDefArray). The code surrounding it might give more insights about your problem

Answer (score 0):

You're most probably calling that update function after the ngOnInit of `EditComponent`

```
ngOnInit() {  // I'm sure this is happening before that update
   console.log(this._editCompSvc.getColDef()); 
}
```

And by the way, it's nicer to write this  :

```
export class Svc { 

constructor() { } 

private _updatedArray:Array<any> = [];
   set colDefs(columns: any) { 
     this._updatedArray.push(columns); 
     console.log('setting the colDefs',columns); 
   }
   get colDef(){ 
        console.log('getting the colDefs',this._updatedArray); 
     return this._updatedArray; 
   }
```

To prove , run above code, you should see "setting the colDefs" before getting it

Comment: No Milad, i just called in my list componnet where i set the columns and get the value in my edit compoennt